# Шифрую строку в php, как расшифровать в C#

Tags: php, c#

Шифрую в PHP так

```
$key = "11111";
$data = 'Test';
$method = "AES-128-CBC";
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $key);
echo $encrypted;
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как расшифровать это это в C#. Нашел метод, но у меня тут что то не сходиться

```
public static string Decrypt(string cipherData, string keyString, string ivString)
{
byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);
byte[] iv  = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ivString);

try
{
    using (var rijndaelManaged =
           new RijndaelManaged {Key = key, IV = iv, Mode = CipherMode.CBC})
    using (var memoryStream = 
           new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(cipherData)))
    using (var cryptoStream =
           new CryptoStream(memoryStream,
               rijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor(key, iv),
               CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    {
        return new StreamReader(cryptoStream).ReadToEnd();
    }
}
catch (CryptographicException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("A Cryptographic error occurred: {0}", e.Message);
    return null;
}
// You may want to catch more exceptions here...
}
```

Comment: для начала проверьте что данные которые у вас получились получились корректными примерно как в мануале для openssl_encrypt **openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -d -in file.encrypted -base64 -pass pass:1234567812345678  -iv 31323334353637383132333435363738** уточните чему будет равен IV если его не задать явно в PHP. возможно он будет добавлен к выводу openssl_encrypt, в этом случае вам надо его будет отделить и передать в IV в .NET.

Comment: Согласно [докам](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) `RijndaelManaged` кажется устаревший алгоритм, используйте [`AesManaged`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged?view=netframework-4.8). Насколько мне известно, там исправлены паддинги, и еще что-то внутри.

Comment: Если вам нужно решение на C#, скорее всего вы можете убрать тег `php` из вопроса, чтобы не путать отвечающих.

Comment: Спасибо за советы, попробую.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, не похоже, что бы часть шифрования была корректной. Согласно комментариям на странице https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php - третий параметр является ключём, а не паролем.

Пример правильного ключа:

```
$key = "395f426c0e5bd914375837483b791d80854dd9a19dd86fd189e94ccade60c5b8";
```

Ключ и iv получают из пароля применением некотого алгоритма. Например pbkdf2.

Таким образом, правильный алгоритм:

1. Сгенерируйте salt.
2. Из пароля и salt сгенерируйте ключ и iv.
3. Запишите salt в данные, затем запишите закриптованные данные.

В моем менеджере паролей pwd есть пример запаковки и распаковки текста полностью совместимый с openssl https://github.com/AlexAtNet/pwd/blob/master/pwd.csx:

```
static Aes CreateAes(byte[] salt, string password) {
   var aes = Aes.Create();
   (aes.Mode, aes.Padding) = (CipherMode.CBC, PaddingMode.PKCS7);
   // 10000 and SHA256 are defaults for pbkdf2 in openssl
   using var rfc2898 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, 10000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
   (aes.Key, aes.IV) = (rfc2898.GetBytes(32), rfc2898.GetBytes(16));
   return aes;
}

static string Decrypt(string password, byte[] data) {
   using var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
   if ("Salted__" != Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ReadBytes(stream, 8)))
      throw new FormatException("Expecting the data stream to begin with Salted__.");
   using var aes = CreateAes(ReadBytes(stream, 8), password);
   using var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
   using var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(stream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
   using var reader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream);
   return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Расшифровывает файлы зашифрованные `openssl aes-256-cbc -d -salt -pbkdf2`.